# error when I try to login with Spring & JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to login with users from database, but I have this error. I think the problem appears in class "UserDetailsServiceImpl". What I have to do to fix this error? I will be grateful for any hint or idea...........................................................................

```
2018-03-16 11:13:40.389 ERROR 6520 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] 
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.continental.qtools.fingerprints.models.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

This is entity "User"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "user_id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int userId;

 @Column(name = "username")
 @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your username")
 private String username;

 @Column(name = "password")
 @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
 @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
 private String password;

 @Column(name = "email")
 @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
 @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
 private String email;

 @Transient
 private String passwordConfirm;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
 private Set<Role> roles;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "users_projects", joinColumns = @JoinColumn)
 private List<Project> projects;

 public User(String username, String password, String email, String passwordConfirm, Set<Role> roles,
        List<Project> projects) {
     super();
     this.username = username;
     this.password = password;
     this.email = email;
     this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
     this.roles = roles;
     this.projects = projects;
}

 public User() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

 public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

 public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

 public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPasswordConfirm() {
    return passwordConfirm;
}

public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
    this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", email=" + email + ", passwordConfirm="
            + passwordConfirm + ", roles=" + roles + ", projects=" + projects + "]";
}
```

}

This is entity "Role"

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "roles")
 public class Role {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "role_id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "role")
 private String role;

 public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

UserDetailsServiceImp

```
 @Service
 public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;


 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    System.out.println("User: " + user.getUsername());

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
    }


    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
            grantedAuthorities);
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a short example and not the whole code and where you get the exact problem.

Comment: Did you follow the stacktrace? ...could not initialize proxy...

Comment: No, how to follow the stacktrace?

Comment: I want to point-out that, don't use entity relations in toString method, you should remove roles and projects from toString method. By default, FetchType for ManyToMany relationship is LAZY but because of the toString() method it fetches the data eagerly.

Comment: Which database are you using? If you're using oracle, check the db-version and the client-version. When you use 10g as a client and 11g as the database, password and username get send to the database in upper-case

Comment: The problem was that i didn't write correct this  section, but now is work

Comment: @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id_ur", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id_ur", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a FetchType.EAGER to the roles property on the user object.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

#### Update: Alternative refactor with Privileges included

**Authority Class instead of Role Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authority")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "authorities_privileges",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;

    public Authority() {
        super();
    }

    public Authority(final String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Authority(String name,
                     Collection<Privilege> privileges) {
        this.name = name;
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }

    public void setPrivileges(Collection<Privilege> privileges) {
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj.toString().equals(this.name)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Authority auth = (Authority) obj;
        if (this.name != null && this.name.equals(auth.name)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Role [name=").append(name).append("]").append("[id=").append(id).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Privilege Class (Optional)**

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Privilege() {
        super();
    }

    public Privilege(final String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "last_password_reset_date")
    private Timestamp lastPasswordResetDate;

    @Column(name = "is_using_2FA")
    private boolean isUsing2FA;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "secret", length = 60)
    private String secret;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Authority> authorities;

    public User() {
        this.secret = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    public User(Long id,
                String username, String firstName, String lastName,
                String email, String password,
                boolean enabled, Timestamp lastPasswordResetDate,
                boolean isUsing2FA, String secret,
                Collection<Authority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
        this.isUsing2FA = isUsing2FA;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(final String username) {
        this.email = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        Date date = new Date();
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public boolean isUsing2FA() {
        return isUsing2FA;
    }

    public void setUsing2FA(boolean isUsing2FA) {
        this.isUsing2FA = isUsing2FA;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastPasswordResetDate() {
        return lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    public void setLastPasswordResetDate(Timestamp lastPasswordResetDate) {
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final User user = (User) obj;
        if (!username.equals(user.username)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("User [id=").append(id).append(", firstName=").append(firstName).append(", lastName=").append(lastName).append(", email=").append(email).append(", password=").append(password).append(", enabled=").append(enabled).append(", isUsing2FA=")
                .append(isUsing2FA).append(", secret=").append(secret).append(", roles=").append(authorities).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**UserBuilder Class**

```
public class UserBuilder {
    private Long bId;
    private String bUsername;
    private String bFirstName;
    private String bLastName;
    private String bEmail;
    private String bPassword;
    private boolean bEnabled;
    private Timestamp bLastPasswordResetDate;
    private boolean bIsUsing2FA;
    private String bSecret;

    private Collection<Authority> bAuthorities;

    public UserBuilder() {
    }

    public UserBuilder(Long bId,
                       String bUsername, String bFirstName, String bLastName,
                       String bEmail, String bPassword, boolean bEnabled,
                       Timestamp bLastPasswordResetDate, boolean bIsUsing2FA, String bSecret,
                       Collection<Authority> authorities) {
        this.bId = bId;
        this.bUsername = bUsername;
        this.bFirstName = bFirstName;
        this.bLastName = bLastName;
        this.bEmail = bEmail;
        this.bPassword = bPassword;
        this.bEnabled = bEnabled;
        this.bLastPasswordResetDate = bLastPasswordResetDate;
        this.bIsUsing2FA = bIsUsing2FA;
        this.bSecret = bSecret;
        this.bAuthorities = bAuthorities;
    }

    public UserBuilder(User user) {
        this.bId = user.getId();
        this.bUsername = user.getUsername();
        this.bFirstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.bLastName = user.getLastName();
        this.bEmail = user.getEmail();
        this.bPassword = user.getPassword();
        this.bEnabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.bLastPasswordResetDate = user.getLastPasswordResetDate();
        this.bIsUsing2FA = user.isUsing2FA();
        this.bSecret = user.getSecret();
    }

    public User createUser() {
        return new User(bId,
                bUsername,
                bFirstName,
                bLastName,
                bEmail,
                bPassword,
                bEnabled,
                bLastPasswordResetDate,
                bIsUsing2FA,
                bSecret,
                bAuthorities
        );
    }


    public UserBuilder bId(Long bId) {
        this.bId = bId;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bUsername(String bUsername) {
        this.bUsername = bUsername;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bFirstName(String bFirstName) {
        this.bFirstName = bFirstName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bLastName(String bLastName) {
        this.bLastName = bLastName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bEmail(String bEmail) {
        this.bEmail = bEmail;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bPassword(String bPassword) {
        Date date = new Date();
        this.bLastPasswordResetDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        this.bPassword = bPassword;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bEnabled(boolean bEnabled) {
        this.bEnabled = bEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bLastPasswordResetDate(Timestamp bLastPasswordResetDate) {
        this.bLastPasswordResetDate = bLastPasswordResetDate;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bIsUsing2FA(boolean bIsUsing2FA) {
        this.bIsUsing2FA = bIsUsing2FA;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bSecret(String bSecret) {
        this.bSecret = bSecret;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder bAuthorities(Collection<Authority> bAuthorities) {
        this.bAuthorities = bAuthorities;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService Class**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String identity) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            final User user = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(identity)).orElseGet(() -> userRepository.findByUsername(identity));

            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + identity);
            }

            //Collection<Authority> authorities = getAuthorities((Collection<Authority>) user.getAuthorities());
            Collection<Authority> authorities = getAuthorities((Collection<Authority>) user.getAuthorities());

            return new UserBuilder(user).bAuthorities(authorities).createUser();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private final Collection<Authority> getAuthorities(final Collection<Authority> authorityList) {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getAuthorityList(authorityList));
    }

    private final List<String> getAuthorityList(final Collection<Authority> authorityList) {
        final List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (final Authority authority : authorityList) {
            authorities.add(authority.getName());

            if (authority.getPrivileges() == null || authority.getPrivileges().isEmpty()) continue;

            // Add all Privileges as Authorities
            for (final Privilege item : authority.getPrivileges()) {
                authorities.add(item.getName());
            }
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    private final Collection<Authority> getGrantedAuthorities(final List<String> authorityList) {
        final List<Authority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<Authority>();
        for (final String authority : authorityList) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new Authority(authority));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

**Repos**

```
public interface PrivilegeRepository extends JpaRepository<Privilege, Long> {

    Privilege findByName(String name);

    @Override
    void delete(Privilege privilege);

}

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Authority, Long> {

    Authority findByName(String name);

    @Override
    void delete(Authority role);

}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findByUsername(String username);

    @Override
    void delete(User user);
}
```

**SetupDataLoader Class (Optional)**

```
@Component
public class SetupDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private boolean alreadySetup = false;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    BeerRepository beerRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if (alreadySetup) {
            return;
        }

        // == create initial privileges
        final Privilege userReadPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("USER_READ_PRIVILEGE");
        final Privilege userWritePrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("USER_WRITE_PRIVILEGE");
        final Privilege beerReadPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("BEER_READ_PRIVILEGE");
        final Privilege beerWritePrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("BEER_WRITE_PRIVILEGE");
        final Privilege passwordPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE");

        // == create initial roles
        final List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = new ArrayList<Privilege>(Arrays.asList(beerReadPrivilege, beerWritePrivilege, userReadPrivilege, userWritePrivilege, passwordPrivilege));
        final List<Privilege> userPrivileges = new ArrayList<Privilege>(Arrays.asList(beerReadPrivilege, beerWritePrivilege));
        final Authority adminAuthority = createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER", userPrivileges);

        // == create initial user
        createUserIfNotFound("rdurden",
                "rdurden@example.com",
                "Rupert",
                "Durden",
                "ILikeBeer2!",
                new ArrayList<Authority>(Arrays.asList(adminAuthority)));

        alreadySetup = true;
    }

    @Transactional
    Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(final String name) {
        Privilege privilege = privilegeRepository.findByName(name);
        if (privilege == null) {
            privilege = new Privilege(name);
            privilege = privilegeRepository.save(privilege);
        }
        return privilege;
    }

    @Transactional
    Authority createRoleIfNotFound(final String name, final Collection<Privilege> privileges) {
        Authority authority = roleRepository.findByName(name);
        if (authority == null) {
            authority = new Authority(name);
        }
        authority.setPrivileges(privileges);
        authority = roleRepository.save(authority);
        return authority;
    }

    @Transactional
    User createUserIfNotFound(final String username, final String email, final String firstName, final String lastName, final String password, final Collection<Authority> authorities) {
        User user = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(email)).orElseGet(() -> userRepository.findByUsername(username));

        if (user != null) return user;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date lastMonthDate = cal.getTime();
        Timestamp lastMonthTimestamp = new Timestamp(lastMonthDate.getTime());

        user = new UserBuilder()
                .bAuthorities(authorities)
                .bUsername(username)
                .bFirstName(firstName)
                .bLastName(lastName)
                .bEmail(email)
                .bPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password))
                .bIsUsing2FA(false)
                .bEnabled(true)
                .bLastPasswordResetDate(lastMonthTimestamp)
                .createUser();

        user = userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)

Comment: Shoot.  Ok.  Yeah, make sure you have @Transnational on the loadUserByUsername method or the UserDetailsServiceImpl class as Jan suggested.  Personally, I like to have my User class implement UserDetails, refactor roles to "Collection<Authority> authorities" and create a "Authority implements GrantedAuthority" class .  I will try to update my answer with an example.  That is just how I like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@Transactional` to method `loadUserByUsername`.